# Path name too long error with tools for apache cordova

Tags: android, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

Trying to build a "Tools for Apache Cordova" project (Visual Studio 2015) for Android fails with the following error

> File path too long on Windows, keep below 240 characters : D:\DevelopmentCustomer\TestProjects\Customer0000\CustomApp001\CustomApp001\platforms\android\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-base\8.1.0\res\drawable-xxhdpi\common_signin_btn_text_disabled_focus_light.9.png

Well, the error is actually obvious: The path to that file is too long. But I don't have much influence on the first part of the path, since our company relies on a specific path structure. On the other hand, that android build path doesn't try to keep it short either.

Is there a workaround to shorten those android pathes?

P.S.: Everything below the platform-directory is generated by the TACO build tools. So, a simple manual adjustment won't do

Comment: Did you resolve this ?

Comment: @Fabii I ended up shortening the 'DevelopmentCustomer' part of the path. Since that is my TFS working folder, I could change it without compromizing our company path structure.